# small MOSFET for switching applications

Tags: mosfet

When I need a general purpose NPN transistor I automatically think of the BC847. Other types that always come back are 2N3904/2N2222. (Is BCxxx more European, and 2Nxxxx more American?)
For N-channel MOSFETs it doesn't look so clear, everybody seems to be using a different type. Can we compile a list of **common MOSFETs** with low \$R_{DS(ON)}\$, say less than 1\$\Omega\$? I think this could be useful for many people.

Possible shopping list:
- N-channel enhancement,
- PTH (TO-92) or SMD (SOT-23),
- \$R_{DS(ON)} < 1\Omega\$,
- logic level (\$V_{GS} < 3V\$)

Comment: Yes: BC... as in BC547 is European, 2N... as in 2N3904 is North American, and 2S... as in 2SC1815 is Japanese. Also, individual manufacturers increasingly use their own codes. This has started long ago with M... for Motorola's (now OnSemi's) power transistors and TIP... for those introduced by TI, and is becoming more and more common.

Comment: "TIP" is short for "TI Power", but now also made by others.

Comment: That's it. After not having produced discrete transistors for maybe at least one or two decades, TI has just recently acquired another company making MOSFETs (CICLON) and is now back in the discretes business... Seems like they now call them NexFET...

Comment: Please, specify gata capacitance for all these. Beefy mosfets can burn anything with their gate capacitance.

Comment: @BarsMonster: you can always add it to the shopping list in the question, especially since it is CW!

Comment: @Barsmonster - You've got a point. But gate capacitance is rarely specified as such. It's usually given is a couple of gate charge values (in nC) which need some interpreting.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a great idea, and I'd like to start with nominating the

OnSemi [**NTR4170N**](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NTR4170N-D.PDF). Quick data:
\$R_{DS(ON)}\$: < 100m\$\Omega\$
\$I_D\$ = 1A @ \$V_{GS}\$ = 1.6V
Package: SOT-23

NXP [**PMN34UN**](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PMN34UN.pdf). Quick data:
\$R_{DS(ON)}\$: < 100m\$\Omega\$
\$I_D\$ = 1A @ \$V_{GS}\$ = 1.3V
Package: [SOT-457](http://www.nxp.com/#/page/content=%5bf=/packages/SOT457.xml%5d)

Comment: Thank you steven. I was inspired by your mentioning the NTR4170N in your recent answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Fairchild [FDV303N](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/pf/FD/FDV303N.html):

Rdson < 600milliohms @ 2.7Vgs
25Vds max
SOT-23

The P-channel equivalent is [FDV304P](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/pf/FD/FDV304P.html).